# swift3 optional value issue

Tags: json, swift, option-type

I have a function to get JSON and put the value into a struct (Job). It prints out the value without optional for the var. But it prints out the struct var with optional. Please kindly help to solve this issue.

```
var newJob = Job()
var joblist:[Job] = []

func parseJSON(json:Any){
    if let okJSON = json as? [Any]{
        for item in okJSON {
            let infoDictionary = item as! [String:String]
            if let activityid       = infoDictionary["ActivityID"]
            {
                newJob.ActivityID=activityid
                print(activityid)
                print(newJob.ActivityID)
            }

            if let companyname      = infoDictionary["CompanyName"] {newJob.CompanyName=companyname}
            if let quantity         = infoDictionary["Quantity"] {newJob.Quantity=quantity}
            if let coupontitle      = infoDictionary["Title"] {newJob.CouponTitle=coupontitle}
            if let couponterms      = infoDictionary["Terms"] {newJob.CouponTerms=couponterms}
            if let expirdate        = infoDictionary["ExpirDate"] {newJob.ExpirDate=expirdate}
            if let contactperson    = infoDictionary["ContactPerson"] {newJob.ContactPerson=contactperson}
            if let tel              = infoDictionary["TEL"] {newJob.TEL=tel}

            joblist.append(newJob)
        }
        print(joblist)
    }
}
```

Here with the print result:

```
3
Optional("3")
2
Optional("2")
1
Optional("1")
[cateringhk.Job(ActivityID: Optional("3"), CompanyName: Optional("ABC\351\233集\351\233集\345\351\233集\345\345\234團"), Quantity: Optional("5"), CouponTitle: Optional("$30現金卷"), CouponTerms: Optional("消費滿$100可以使用\r\n台灯固定环E27灯头 \r\n黑色白色固定扣 \r\n台灯灯罩床头灯具固定环配件 \r\n[交易快照]"), ExpirDate: Optional("2017-11-24"), ContactPerson: Optional("陳先生"), TEL: Optional("96855000")), cateringhk.Job(ActivityID: Optional("2"), CompanyName: Optional("皇上皇點心集團"), Quantity: Optional("31"), CouponTitle: Optional("$30現金卷"), CouponTerms: Optional("消費滿$100可以使用"), ExpirDate: Optional("2017-11-24"), ContactPerson: Optional("陳先生"), TEL: Optional("96855000")), cateringhk.Job(ActivityID: Optional("1"), CompanyName: Optional("八樂園酒樓"), Quantity: Optional("22"), CouponTitle: Optional("$20消費券"), CouponTerms: Optional("每1帳單只可以使用一用一\345\274張消費券"), ExpirDate: Optional("2017-11-24"), ContactPerson: Optional("陳小姐"), TEL: Optional("94567821"))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is normal if the properties in the struct are also declared as optionals. In this case the unwrapping with optional binding has actually no effect.

To avoid that declare the property as non-optional and assign a default value for example

```
struct Job {

  var activityID = ""
  ...

}

   newJob.activityID = infoDictionary["ActivityID"] ?? ""
```

But assigning an empty string twice looks cumbersome. I'd add an initializer to the struct to take a dictionary, declare the properties as constants and handle the default value in the `init` method.

```
struct Job {

  let activityID : String
  ...

  init(dict: [String:String]) {
      activityID = dict["ActivityID"] ?? ""
      ... 
  }

}
```

Note:

Please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter